# Latex is mixing roman and decimal numbers

Tags: page-numbering, pagestyle

I am writing a document whose imports were given by the university with the {memoir} class. My problem is that Latex is showing the pages until the first chapter as roman number and after is showing the numbers as decimals, starting again on page 1.
I've already searched on other posts but I don't have `\pagestyle{empty}` defined or any other command mentioned. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Here is my configuration:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{memoir} % for a short document
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}

%\makeglossaries

\input{extra/glossary.tex}

\usepackage [vscale=0.76,includehead]{geometry}   
\usepackage{times}            
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
\OnehalfSpacing
\setSingleSpace{1.05}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent


%===================================== packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % font = times
\usepackage{helvet} % font sf = helvetica
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}%textquotesingle
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{footnote}
%============================================
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
%==============================================
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
%Style des têtes de section, headings, chapitre
\headstyles{komalike}
\nouppercaseheads
%\chapterstyle{dash}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\sffamily\thepage}{}{\sffamily\leftmark} 
\makeoddhead{headings}{\sffamily\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\thepage}
%\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{} % Pages chapitre. 
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
%\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\thechapter ---}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\relax}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{ \sffamily\bfseries \LARGE}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{ \sffamily\bfseries \LARGE}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}



% Title page formatting
\newcommand{\jury}[1]{% 
\gdef\juryB{#1}} 
\newcommand{\juryB}{} 
\newcommand{\session}[1]{% 
\gdef\sessionB{#1}} 
\newcommand{\sessionB}{} 
\newcommand{\option}[1]{% 
\gdef\optionB{#1}} 
\newcommand{\optionB} {}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{% 
\vfill{}  \large\par\noindent  
\begin{center}\juryB \bigskip\sessionB\end{center}
\vspace{-1.5cm}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{% 
\vspace{-1.5cm}\noindent\includegraphics[height=12ex]{pics/logo-uga.png}\hfill\raisebox{2ex}{\includegraphics[height=14ex]{pics/logoINP.png}}\\
\bigskip
\begin{center} \large
% =======================End of title page formatting

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{English} 
\frontmatter
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
```

Comment: This is a very common way to paginate a book. If you have been given a template by your universe that does this it is probably totally intentional!

Comment: Thank your for your reply pst! Maybe it is, I just thought very weird since I have never pay attention to books like this. Thank you :)

Comment: (I have to love my own typo with "universe" for "university" here!) Actually I find this traditional pagination impractical for documents that also are used online, since with a pdf reader you may sometimes be confused when following a page reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out by testing and error:

`\frontmatter` should be commented by doing this we can stop the roman numbers.

`\mainmatter` should be removed since it will stop the reset to the numbering.

Comment: It would have been helpful if original query had noted that the document was using the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` directives. Without this crucial bit of information, there was no way for readers to provide a (correct) diagnosis of the situation.